# What's wrong with creating a dictionary in ClickHouse?

Tags: json, clickhouse

I need to create a dictionary in ClickHouse, which will request data via the API. The dictionary is being created, but when I open it I get errors.

I create a dictionary like this:

```
CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS dbName.AppDict
(
    Name String,
    AppType Int32
)
PRIMARY KEY Name
SOURCE(HTTP(
    url 'http://my_service.ru/api/Services/list?Offset=0'
    format 'JSONCompactStringsEachRowWithNamesAndTypes'
    credentials(user 'user' password 'xyz')
))
LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED())
LIFETIME(60);
```

When I open the dictionary, I get the following error:

```
ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: localhost, port: 8123; Code: 27. DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected '[' before: '{"result":{"totalCount":2,"services":[{"version": "1.0.1","platformOS": "windows","name": "my_service1",: While executing JSONCompactEachRowRowInputFormat. (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED) (version 21.11.2.2 (official build))
```

by url from `http://my_service.ru/api/Services/list?Offset=0` I get the following response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "totalCount": 2,
        "services": [
            {
                "version": "1.0.1",
                "platformOS": "windows",
                "name": "my_service1",
                "appType": 0
            },
            {
                "version": "2.0.0",
                "platformOS": "windows",
                "name": "my_service2",
                "appType": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What needs to be done so that when I open a dictionary I get?

| Name | AppType |
| --- | --- |
| my_service1 | 1.0.1 |
| my_service2 | 2.0.0 |

Comment: it's not JSONCompactStringsEachRowWithNamesAndTypes.

Comment: You can create VIEW with JSONExtract `select JSONExtract.... from http( . )` and use this VEIW as a dictionary source.